# how do you read a pytables table into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I have built a pytables table and filled it using append like so:

```
h5file = open_file("FGBS.h5", mode = "a")
group = h5file.create_group("/", 'hybrid')
table = h5file.create_table(group, 'z4', Hybrid ,filters= tb.Filters(5, "blosc"))
```

using:

```
class Hybrid(IsDescription):
    dateTime = Time32Col()
    price = Float64Col()
    quantity = Float64Col()
    bidPrc = Float64Col()
    bidSize = Float64Col()
    askPrc = Float64Col()
    askSize = Float64Col()
```

and appending to the table:

```
           if 0 in dictInstrumentsData[message.symbol].bidPrice and 0 in dictInstrumentsData[message.symbol].askPrice:
                hybrid = table.row
                hybrid["dateTime"] = message.timestamp * 0.001
                hybrid["price"] = message.price
                hybrid["quantity"] = message.size
                hybrid["bidPrc"] = dictInstrumentsData[message.symbol].bidPrice[0]
                hybrid["bidSize"] = dictInstrumentsData[message.symbol].bidSize[0]
                hybrid["askPrc"] = dictInstrumentsData[message.symbol].askPrice[0]
                hybrid["askSize"] = dictInstrumentsData[message.symbol].askSize[0]

                hybrid.append()
```

now I am trying to read it back into a pandas dataframe like this:

```
a = tb.open_file("FGBS.h5")
table = a.root.quote.z4
c = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table)
```

but then when I look at c all I get is:

```
                                          0       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          1       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          2       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          3       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          4       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          5       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          6       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          7       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          8       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          9       \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                       ...                        \
0                      ...                         

                                          164401  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164402  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164403  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164404  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164405  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164406  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164407  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164408  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164409  \
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411   

                                          164410  
0  /hybrid/z4.row (Row), pointing to row #164411  

[1 rows x 164411 columns]
```

not a dataframe with columns based on the Hybrid columns and rows for each append. Can anyone help show me what I  am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly read the data from the table.  [Table.read](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#tables.Table.read) will pull in the entire table, and [Table.read_where](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#tables.Table.read_where) allows you to apply a conditional statement to filter the data that is returned.

```
a = tb.open_file("FGBS.h5")
table = a.root.quote.z4
c = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table.read())
```